# Conditional WHERE Clause in a Table Valued Function

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql

I have a table valued function

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateRange] 
    (
        @StartDate date,
        @EndDate date,
        @Location varchar(25),
        @Device varchar(25)
    ) 
    RETURNS TABLE 
    AS
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE Date < @EndDate AND
              Date > @StartDate AND
              Location = @Location AND
              Device = @Device 

    );
```

Now I would like to give the user the option to use NULL as location parameter and or device parameter so he/she gets all data independent of the location and device back

What would be the most elegant and efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateRange] 
    (
        @StartDate date,
        @EndDate date,
        @Location varchar(25) = NULL,
        @Device varchar(25) = NULL
    ) 
    RETURNS TABLE 
    AS
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE 
          Date < @EndDate 
          AND Date > @StartDate 
          AND ( @Location IS NULL OR (@Location IS NOT NULL AND Location = @Location))
          AND ( @Device IS NULL OR (@Device IS NOT NULL AND Device = @Device ))

    )
```

IF the `device` and `location` columns can actually be NULL, you might want to consider this option though:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateRange] 
    (
        @StartDate date,
        @EndDate date,
        @Location varchar(25) = NULL,
        @Device varchar(25) = NULL
    ) 
    RETURNS TABLE 
    AS
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE 
          Date < @EndDate 
          AND Date > @StartDate 
          AND ( @Location IS NULL OR Location = @Location)
          AND ( @Device IS NULL OR Device = @Device )

    )
```

This would work if you're using a UD table type for the location, as you asked about in your comment. Just make sure the input parameter is Read Only. 
However, you cannot pass NULL into a table type parameter, you have to pass in an empty parameter object of that type :

```
CREATE TYPE LocationsType AS TABLE 
( LocationName VARCHAR(25));

CREATE TABLE MyTable (Date datetime, Location varchar(25), Device varchar(25));

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateRange] 
    (
        @StartDate date,
        @EndDate date,
        @Location LocationsType READONLY,
        @Device varchar(25) = NULL
    ) 
    RETURNS TABLE 
    AS
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE 
          Date < @EndDate 
          AND Date > @StartDate 
          AND ( ((select count(*) FROM @Location) = 0) OR Location IN (select LocationName from @Location))
          AND ( @Device IS NULL OR Device = @Device )

    )
```

Call it:

```
declare @l LocationsType

select *
from [dbo].[DateRange] (getDate(), GetDate(), @l,NULL)
```

Comment: Is this also possible with a parameter @Location which would be a table valued type ? so I can pass more than one location value ? 
So if there are values in the table valued type it gets the rows with this specific locations, if there is NULL it returns all rows?

Comment: that would be probably just slightly more complex, but no big deal.
If you want, I'll add that variation

Comment: Just added a little to the answer, as per your question in the comments

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way according to my own testing is:
*Remark: only valid for NON-NULLABLE columns, as commented by Aaron.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateRange] 
(
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date,
    @Location varchar(25),
    @Device varchar(25)
) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Date < @EndDate 
      AND Date > @StartDate 
      AND Location = CASE WHEN @Location IS NULL THEN Location ELSE @Location END
      AND Device = CASE WHEN @Device IS NULL THEN Device ELSE @Device END

);
```

There is another way, using `ISNULL(@Location,Location)` instead of `CASE` expression, however, as elegant as it may be, it is less efficient then `CASE`.

Comment: This can change the query semantics in the event that the `Location` or `Device` column is actually `NULL`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are correct, my testings were on NON-NULLABLE columns, added remark to my answer.

Comment: Also can you add some evidence that `ISNULL` is less efficient than a `CASE` *expression* (it's not a statement)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I replaced "statement" with "expression". as for the efficiency of CASE over ISNULL and OR, I will look for a link to post as it has been discussed many times before. Thank you for the remarks.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, found a way to do the same with Table Valued Types

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateRange] 
    (
        @StartDate date,
        @EndDate date,
        @Location TVT.Location ReadOnly,
        @Device TVT.Device ReadOnly
    ) 
    RETURNS TABLE 
    AS
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE Date < @EndDate 
              Date > @StartDate AND 
              (Location IN (SELECT Location FROM @Location) OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from @Location)) AND
              (Device IN (SELECT Device FROM @Device) OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @Device))

    )
```